# Trouble referencing an array marshaled as unmanaged with a constant size

Tags: c#, arrays, ref

I am trying to understand what is going on behind the curtain when I create an array with a constant size as below:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
public float[] constArray;
```

I understand that I can use the `fixed` key word, but then `ref` is no longer an options, and all pointer operations must be inside a fixed expression.

What I am trying to do is parse an XML file and store at an given index in the array. So if there are 10 elements in the file I might set up the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    readElement("element", ref constArray[i]);
}
```

However, `constArray[i]` is `null`.

Maybe a further instantiation is require, but then what is the point of marshalling.  I thought marshalling created the object that `ref` operates on to create a reference.

I read through [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) and [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) with out finding much information.  I also read a few others such as [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) and [referencing arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szasx730.aspx) with out much progress.

I just can seem to find a resource that provides a good conceptual understanding.  So any resources, as well as an answer, would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Blake

Answer (score 1):

First of all - `float` cannot be null (if you want nullable float then use `float?`), so your problem might be in uninitialized array?

Overral [`MarshalAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx)

> Indicates how to marshal the data between managed and unmanaged code.

Is that what you want? or is your goal as simple as following

```
float [] constArray = new float[10];
```

Are you sure that you need simple array - why not to use `List<float>`?

Comment: After 5 years, I've forgotten exactly why I wanted to use an array.  What I do remember was trying to imitate a c-style way of setting up the memory for the array such that I could dump values at the location of the pointer.

I think my goal was as simple as `float [] constArray = new float[10];`.

For the sake of understanding, why doesn't the reference to the ith index of constArray resolve?